# getting vertex points of GeometryModel3D to draw a wireframe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I've loaded a 3d model using Helix toolking like this

```
modelGroupScull = importer.Load("C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\a.obj");
GeometryModel3D modelScull = (GeometryModel3D)modelGroupScull.Children[0];
```

and I also have _3DTools that can draw lines from point-to-point in 3d space. now to draw a wireframe of my GeometryModel3D I guess I have to cycle to its vertexes and add them to ScreenSpaceLines3D.

```
ScreenSpaceLines3D wireframe = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();

// need to cycle through all vertexes of modelScull as Points, to add them to wireframe
wireframe.Points.Add(new Point3D(1, 2, 3));


wireframe.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
wireframe.Thickness = 3;

Viewport3D1.Children.Add(wireframe);
```

But... how do I actually get this vertex points?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer. It did add the points

```
        ScreenSpaceLines3D wireframe = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();

        MeshGeometry3D mg3 = (MeshGeometry3D)modelScull.Geometry;

        foreach (Point3D point3D in mg3.Positions)
        {
            wireframe.Points.Add(point3D);
        }


        wireframe.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
        wireframe.Thickness = 1;

        Viewport3D1.Children.Add(wireframe);
```

but the wireframe is messed up )

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/3a70930150757c6bee9153b02bc459dd.png))</sub>

maybe someone knows of other ways to draw wireframes? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the trigons are drawn with index buffers (to prevent extra rotations of vertices) Take a look at the TriangleIndices:

if you do something like this: (not tested it)

```
    MeshGeometry3D mg3 = (MeshGeometry3D)modelScull.Geometry;

    for(int index=0;index<mg3.TriangleIndices.Count; index+=3)
    {
        ScreenSpaceLines3D wireframe = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();

        wireframe.Points.Add(mg3.Positions[mg3.TriangleIndices[index]]);
        wireframe.Points.Add(mg3.Positions[mg3.TriangleIndices[index+1]]);
        wireframe.Points.Add(mg3.Positions[mg3.TriangleIndices[index+2]]);
        wireframe.Points.Add(mg3.Positions[mg3.TriangleIndices[index]]);

        wireframe.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
        wireframe.Thickness = 1;

        Viewport3D1.Children.Add(wireframe);
    }
```

But, this can create some overdraw (2 lines on the same coordinates) and probably very slow.
If you put each side into a list and use something like a Distinct on it, it will be better.

The problem with the ScreenSpaceLines3D is that will continue the line, instead of create 1 line (start/end).

If you can manage a algoritm that tries to draw you model with 1 line, it will go faster.

Wireframes are very slow in WPF. (because they are created with trigons)

Comment: idea sound nice, but it throws Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Windows.Media.Int32Collection'

Comment: I updated it, are there any problems now? Forgot the `Count` property, maybee you need `Count()` Can you update your post and add the new image? (show the previous also)

Comment: still looks messed up and veeery slow ( guess will have to look for some other method. )

Comment: My bad, try again plz.. i forgot something.. It won't be faster, but shouldn't mesh up anymore. Those TriangleIndices are indices to positions. Let me know plz.

Comment: the mesh looks correct, but veeery slow ) took about a minute or so to load up.

Comment: Thats because all triangles will be handled as single mesh. Now it's your turn to try figure out, what lines you don't need, and if you want to speed it up, try to create a few lines that will handle more trigons. (1 touch draw). Maybee you could try to create a brute force to calculate the best way to draw the skull with a less as possible lines. (can you add the correct drawing also plz?)

Comment: As you can see, it's very dense. Many lines(meshes) are created (with their own matrices for rotation/translation) And will be drawn separately. The ScreenSpaceLines3D normally isn't used for drawing complex wireframes. But i think it's a challenge to draw it as one or few lines possible.

Comment: by the way, maybe there's an option to render the mesh just as flat shaded?

Comment: Flatshading doesn't reduce the amount of polygons. If there is a way to 'optimize' the model, would help more.

Comment: no, no, I mean that I need to represent the mesh as it is, I shouldn't optimize it. So if it too slow to show as wireframe, showing it as gray flat shaded mesh would also do. )

Comment: I think render it a one mesh will speed up much, also you'll see some depth.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the vertex points in [MeshGeometry3D.Positions Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.positions.aspx)

```
foreach (var point3D in modelScull.Geometry.Positions)
```